# Same class name in different packages

Tags: java, package

Can same class exist in multiple packages? 
In other words, can I have `Foo.java` class in `com.test.package1` and `com.test.package2`?

**Update**

Now I copied class from package 1 and placed in to package 2 and now I am creating an instance of that class, I want this instance to point to class present in package 1 but currently it points to package1 path, how can i modify it?

Oh so I cannot do something like:

```
Foo = new Foo() // pointing to Foo class in package 1
Foo = new Foo() // pointing to Foo class in package 2
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, you can have two classes with the same name in multiple packages. However, you **can't import both classes in the same file** using two `import` statements. You'll have to fully qualify one of the class names if you really need to reference both of them.

---

Example: Suppose you have

**pkg1/SomeClass.java**

```
package pkg1;
public class SomeClass {
}
```

**pkg2/SomeClass.java**

```
package pkg2;
public class SomeClass {
}
```

and **Main.java**

```
import pkg1.SomeClass;   // This will...
import pkg2.SomeClass;   // ...fail

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new SomeClass();
    }
}
```

If you try to compile, you'll get:

```
$ javac Main.java
Main.java:2: pkg1.SomeClass is already defined in a single-type import
import pkg2.SomeClass;
^
1 error
```

**This however** does compile:

```
import pkg1.SomeClass;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new SomeClass();
        new pkg2.SomeClass();   // <-- not imported.
    }
}
```

Comment: is it a good practice in Java? Or is it advised to avoid such names?

Comment: I would say it's not a good practice if you control the code of both packages. One exception would be if you're supporting, say, two versions of a model, and have `com.company.model.v1.Cat` and `com.company.model.v2.Cat` and you're implementing some migration code that need to reference both. Another exception would be if you're relying on multiple external libraries that use the same class names.

Comment: Okay, what about when you are following some ddd and clean code approach. From that perspective which takes precedence(or you would prefer)? Java's "dont use type w/ package name" vs ddd/clean code approach. Like mentioned here https://gist.github.com/cardil/b29a81efd64a09585076fe00e3d34de7#alternatives

Comment: So, first of all, I have programmed in Java the past 25 years, and I've only found this to be a limiting factor once or twice. I'm not sure how DDD and "clean code" comes into play here. To me "clean code" is strongly correlated with "easy to understand" code, and if you start _renaming classes_ I can't see how that improves understandability to be honest. In those _very_ rare occasions where you _have_ to deal with two classes with the same name in the same file, I probably prefer fully qualified names to really hammer home exactly which class I'm referring to.

Comment: its been only 2 months coding in java and I encountered this issue 3 times, that why wanted your opinion. Thanks (Y)

Answer (score 5):

Sure can but you'll need to distinguish which one you want when calling them in other packages if both are included within a source file.

Response to Comment:

```
com.test.package1.Foo myFoo = new com.test.package1.Foo();
com.test.package2.Foo myOtherFoo = new com.test.package2.Foo();
```

Comment: so here is my next question, how can i do that because currently i am calling them but instead of referring to package2 class, code is referring to package 1 class.

Answer (score 3):

i was taken to this page by google when i had the error `a type with the same simple name is already defined by the single-type-import`. i fixed this error (AFTER A VERY LONG TIME) by realising the line `import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;` had snuck into the very top of my imports whilst i had the line `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;` at the bottom of my imports.

Comment: With your help fixed similar error. I was importing "java.util.logging.Logger" and "org.slf4j.Logger" simultaneously. Just forgot to remote the first one, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

So I was looking for a smarter solution than just using fully qualified names on one or both of the implemented classes.

If you create a private class, and extend your class, you are free to use the class, without writing the full package name each time.

Package 1

```
    namespace namespace1.Logger
    {
        public class Log
        {
            public void Foo1(){}
        }
    }
```

Package 2

```
    namespace namespace2.Logger
    {
        public class Log
        {
            public void Foo2(){}
        }
    }
```

My class implementation

```
    //using namespace1.Logger;
    //using namespace2.Logger;

    namespace MyProject
    {
        public class MyClass
        {
            public MyClass()
            {
                LoggerA a = new LoggerA();
                LoggerB b = new LoggerB();
                a.Foo1();
                b.Foo2();
            }

            private class LoggerA : namespace1.Logger.Log { }
            private class LoggerB : namespace2.Logger.Log { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what language is this? the question was about java