# Same class name in a subpackage

Tags: java, package

So I found this answer and it shows that I have to import one class and fully qualify the class that I don't import.
[Same class name in different packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055634/same-class-name-in-different-packages/4055649)

However, how do I do that for classes with the same name but in a subpackage and being used as a parameter?

Say I have:

pkg1/SomeClass.java

```
package pkg1;
public class SomeClass {
}
```

pkg1/subpkg1/SomeClass.java

```
package pkg1.subpkg1;
public class SomeClass {
}
```

Then a different class in pkg1 needs to use both:
pkg1/LastClass.java

```
package pkg1;

public class LastClass {
    public void someMethod(SomeClass someClass) {
    }

    public void someOtherMethod(subpkg1.SomeClass someClass) {
    }
}
```

This does not seem to work (cannot resolve symbol subpkg1). How can I use the class in the subpackage?

Comment: You have to use the fully-qualified name. It's not like directories where you have "relative" names.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had to use the full package path `(com.[...].[...].pkg1.subpkg1.SomeClass)`.